# Homepage scrolling issues

Tags: scroll

This is my homepage: http://redvectordesign.com/demo/

As you can see, it's quite unique in its approach. The issue I have is that the vertical scroll bar appears on the right side of the browser for some monitors but not for others (This must be due to resolution) The layout changes alignment for tablets and mobile (in those cases, the vertical scroll bar is understandable) but is there some way to limit the vertical scroll bar for larger resolutions (ie desktop and laptop) because otherwise, the elements (coffee cup, paper etc) move up and down which doesn't look great. Any advice would be welcome! I'm a noob so sorry if my question sounds dumb :(

Comment: wheer are your working codes...??

Comment: Im actually not the programmer, im the designer. The developer is a little tied up so I thought I would try to figure it out. Where would I be able to find this? Or if someone could explain the logic of how to get this done, I could tell the developer once he gets freed up.

Comment: Seeing your codes it will be easier to answer...

Comment: Okay. Can you tell me which file you would like me to send across to you? Eg. Style.css etc etc?